# Graphviz - aligning nodes and clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to draw a finite state diagram with Graphviz but I cannot get it like I want it. Here's what I have written so far :

```
digraph G {
    rankdir = LR;

    subgraph cluster_op1 {

        subgraph cluster_0 {
            1 -> 2 [label="a"]  
        }

        subgraph cluster_1 {
            3 -> {4 6} [label="&epsilon;"]
            4 -> 5 [label="b"]
            5 -> 4 [label="&epsilon;"]
            5 -> 6 [label="&epsilon;"]
        }

        subgraph cluster_2 {
            7 -> {8 10} [label="&epsilon;"]
            8 -> 9 [label="c"]
            9 -> 8 [label="&epsilon;"]
            9 -> 10 [label="&epsilon;"]
        }   

        2 -> 3 [label="&epsilon;"]
        6 -> 7 [label="&epsilon;"]
    }

    subgraph cluster_op2 {

        subgraph cluster_3 {
            11 -> {12 14} [label="&epsilon;"]
            12 -> 13 [label="ab"]
            13 -> 12 [label="&epsilon;"]
            13 -> 14 [label="&epsilon;"]
        }   

        subgraph cluster_4 {
            15 -> 16 [label="c"]    
        }

        14->15 [label="&epsilon;"]
    }

    0 -> {1 11} [label="&epsilon;"]
    {10 16} -> 17 [label="&epsilon;"]
}
```

Here's what it looks like : 
[image]

What I want is :

1. All the nodes within `cluster_op1` to be aligned horizontally (same for `cluster_op2`)
2. `cluster_op2` to be centered below `cluster_op1`
3. The edges from node `0` to `cluster_op1` and `cluster_op2` to be the same length (same for the edges from those two clusters to node `17`)

Comment: Thanks for useful code and clear questions!

Comment: By the way, your requirement 2. and 3. are contradictory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a hack more than a real solution but it gives you what you want, at least for the case presented here.

It uses three elements:

**group** to facilitate straight lines between nodes,

**weight** to help if group gets confused by one node pointing to two other nodes, all of which being in the same group; and to bring the clusters in line between them,

**invis** edge to align `cluster_op2` below `cluster_op1` - so it's not centered but manually adjusted.

In addition, I have replaced `b -> a` with `a -> b[ dir = back ]` where applicable; this I regard just as good practice to avoid bugs that are difficult to discover.

So this is your edited code:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir = LR;
    0, 1, 2, 15, 16, 17
    3, 4, 5, 6     [ group = 1 ];
    7, 8, 9, 10    [ group = 2 ];
    11, 12, 13, 14 [ group = 3 ];
    2 -> 11[ style = invis ];

    subgraph cluster_op1 {

        subgraph cluster_0 {
            1 -> 2 [ label="a" ]; 
        }

        subgraph cluster_1 {
            3 -> 4 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 4 ];
            3 -> 6 [ label="&epsilon;" ];
            4 -> 5 [ label="b" ];
            4 -> 5 [ label="&epsilon;", dir = back];
            5 -> 6 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 4 ];
        }

        subgraph cluster_2 {
            7 -> {8 10} [label="&epsilon;"]
            8 -> 9 [label="c"]
            8 -> 9 [ label="&epsilon;", dir = back ];
            9 -> 10 [label="&epsilon;"]
        }   

        2 -> 3 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 10 ;]
        6 -> 7 [ label="&epsilon;" ];
    }

    subgraph cluster_op2 {

        subgraph cluster_3 {
            11 -> 12 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 4 ];
            11 -> 14 [ label="&epsilon;" ];
            12 -> 13 [ label="ab" ];
            12 -> 13 [ label="&epsilon;", dir = back ];
            13 -> 14 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 4 ];
        }   

        subgraph cluster_4 {
            15 -> 16 [label="c"]    
        }

        14->15 [ label="&epsilon;", weight = 10 ];
    }

    0 -> {1 11} [label="&epsilon;"]
    {10 16} -> 17 [label="&epsilon;"]
}
```

which yields

[image]